# Open Visualforce Page through @future method

Tags: apex, visualforce, error-messages, future

I have a future method (callout) and I would like to open a visualforce page to display if there are errors.

Is it possible?

For example :

```
@future(callout=true)
public static void doSomething()
{
    //callout code
    //after this callout code, if there is an error so should open vf page
}
```

Comment: Visualforce would be able to trigger future method by any action but results cannot be displayed because future methods are asynchronous by nature.

Comment: Thank you , Is there an another way to display errors to the user when a future function failed ?  (For example , I could send mails but it is not so nice and there is also the problem of  SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED)

Comment: There's not really any way to do that. For all you know, the user already turned off their machine before the future method started running.

Comment: One option would be to create task or activities to the parent record and use workflows to send email notifications.